# CSS Background Hover Text

Tags: html, css

I have a background image that is getting set an opacity 0.3, then when hovering, getting set to 0.8, as seen in the css code.

The image code.

```
<td background="images/1a.png" class="logo" width="160" height="160">
    <div class="ch-info">
        <h3><br>Add New Deal</h3>
    </div>
</td>
```

The css code.

```
.ch-info {
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 20px;
/*  margin: 0 30px; 
    padding: 45px 0 0 0;*/
    height: 140px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
    color: #d3d3d3;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
.logo
{
    opacity:0.3;
    filter:alpha(opacity=30); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center; 
}
.logo:hover
{
    opacity:0.8;
    filter:alpha(opacity=80); /* For IE8 and earlier */ 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
}
```

The text and the background do the hovering effect, I want the text to stay solid, and the background to hover at a 0.8 when the mouse is over the background and the Text to stay Solid regardless if the background is hovered or not.

Comment: `.ch-info` has parent `.logo` and children inherit opacity from their parent. Remove opacity from `.logo` and only apply it to `.logo:hover`

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem, it simply removes the inactive background effect to 1 (or standard), and when hovered it sets the background and text to opacity to .8 for both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I stated in the comments, children inherit opacity from their parent. The `.ch-info` class inherits its opacity from `.logo`, so you cannot have the immediate parent be `.logo`.

That being said, just have a `<div class="logo"></div>` before `.ch-info` that uses `position: absolute;`, is the same height as either the `<td>` or `.ch-info`, and has the desired background... However, you would have to use `position:relative;` on `.ch-info` so the `z-index` does not become a problem.

***DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/mSg97/3/***

**HTML:**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td width="160" height="160">
        <div class="logo" style="background:blue;"></div>
        <div class="ch-info">
             <h3>Add New Deal</h3>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
 <tr>
    <td width="160" height="160">
        <div class="logo" style="background:red;"></div>
        <div class="ch-info">
             <h3>Add New Deal</h3>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="160" height="160">
        <div class="logo" style="background:orange;"></div>
        <div class="ch-info">
             <h3>Add New Deal</h3>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**CSS:**

```
.logo
{
    width:160px; 
    height:160px;
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0.3;
    filter:alpha(opacity=30); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center; 
}
.logo:hover
{
    opacity:0.8;
    filter:alpha(opacity=80); /* For IE8 and earlier */ 
}
.ch-info {
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 20px;
/*  margin: 0 30px; 
    padding: 45px 0 0 0;*/
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
    color: #d3d3d3;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

---

***EDIT:***
However, this situation seems better suited for jQuery.  I have provided an example below.

***DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/mSg97/4/***

Comment: how would i go about doing this if i had multiple background logos, just make a separate css code for each one? because you specified image 1a.png in .logo

Comment: Personally, I would just change the `style` attribute rather than making multiple css classes (I am pretty lazy). Make sure to remove `background` from `.logo` in CSS. Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/mSg97/2/ . Let me know if you need anything else, I am happy to help.

Comment: also this causes the text to become transparent with the background, i wanted the text to be solid or above the image at all times.

Comment: Ah, I see it. This is because of [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index). You can fix this by making the `.ch-info`'s **position:relative;** and remove the height attribute - http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/mSg97/3/. However, I, personally, would use [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) in this situation rather than CSS.

Comment: Here is an example using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/mSg97/4/ . NOTE: you remove `.logo:hover` from your CSS.

Comment: i see what you mean, when you highlight the text the background goes back to .3.

could this be fixed by adding <a link> attribute to the text and when the text gets hover it will display the background back to .8?

Comment: @Sickest CSS can only do so much, in this case, we should use javascript (but I recommend jQuery).  Check my solution, added a couple possible ways of going about this.

Comment: i used your method, it works perfect. i don't have enough rep to up vote you tho

Comment: @Sickest glad I could help! Make sure to accept the answer (doing so will raise your rep) - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this css class

```
.logo:hover .ch-info {
    opacity: 0.375;
}
```

Comment: no, that makes the text stay transparent at .375 regardless if its hovered or not.

Comment: Ok i missunderstood your question then. So your text should always be visible completely but the background should be 30-80% transparent?

Comment: yes, you got it, i want the text to stay visible regardless of the background

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying the font, etc., inside of the ".logo:hover"?

```
    .logo:hover
    {
        opacity:0.8;
        filter:alpha(opacity=80); /* For IE8 and earlier */ 
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:center;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        font-size: 20px;
        height: 140px;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
        -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
        color: #d3d3d3;
        text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
        vertical-align:middle;
        text-align:center;
    }
```

Comment: yep, doesn't work. that just sets the text inactive to a opacity of .8 instead of 1, which is actually worse.